# Counting cells when in another cell there is specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi i need to count column of cells where specific value is when in another cell has specific value.
I am using countifs function but i get and error. The cell G6 is drop down list when i want to change the word between MULTI and SINGLE and count the cells in "Page1" from the column when there is "Multi" Or "Single"

My code:

```
COUNTIFS(G6;"MULTI";'Page1'!B:B;"Multi")
```

How can I do it? Can you help please?

Comment: Please clarify: you need to perform the count only when there is the word "Multi" in the cell G6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because your ranges are not the same. That being said, it looks like you need something like:

```
=COUNTIF('Page1'!B:B;G6)
```

Otherwise maybe a nested `IF()` to check if `G6` has "MULTI" or "SINGLE" or another value in it.

Comment: Ok so i can combine it with IF right so i take "COUNTIF('Page1'!B:B;G6)" and add if to check the value in G6 is multi or single?
Can you tell me how can i combine IF with this COUNTIF please? I would really appriciate it. I need to check with IF is in G6 is MULTI and ELSE if there is SINGLE

Comment: It would now just auto-pick whichever value is in `G6` but if you want to be specific you can try: `=IF(OR(G6="SINGLE";G6="MULTI");COUNTIF('Page1'!B:B;G6);"There is another value in G6")` @MateuszJablonski